# PHP Multidimensional Array of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Can anyone help me with this little problem please? I need to get (echo) the name, id and link from an array but after hours trying I have not been able, see the array below... Thank you in advanced.

```
            Array
            (
                [campaigns] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Campaign Object
                            (
                                [name] => My name 1
                                [id] => 123456789012
                                [link] => 123456789012
                            )

                        [1] => Campaign Object
                            (
                                [name] => My name 2
                                [id] => 123456789012
                                [link] => 123456789012
                            )

                        [2] => Campaign Object
                            (
                                [name] => My name 3
                                [id] => 123456789012
                                [link] => 123456789012
                            )
                    )
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know which campaign you want, you can get it like this:

```
echo($data['campaigns'][0]->name);
echo($data['campaigns'][0]->id);
echo($data['campaigns'][0]->link);
```

If you want to loop through all of them, you could do something like this:

```
foreach ($data['campaigns'] as $item) {
    echo($item->name . "\n");
    echo($item->id . "\n");
    echo($item->link . "\n");
}
```

This is all a bit of a guess because we don't know what the `Campaign` class actually looks like - there may be a `getName()` method that you should be using instead of just accessing the name value directly, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array['campaigns'] as $key => $value){
    echo "Name: ".$value->name." ID: ".$value->id." Link: ".$value->link."\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Question is a little light on details to debug but have you tried this?

```
<?php echo $campaigns[0]->name; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I don't use PHP on a daily basis, will fix.